# Using GraphQL to list all tags of a FFmpeg and search for releases

Tags: git, github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to use GraphQL to get all tags of FFmpeg and later get the downloadUrl of each tag release.

In the GraphQL Explorer, I used the following query:

```
query {
    repository(owner: "FFmpeg", name: "FFmpeg") {
        refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100) {
            nodes {
                repository {
                    releases(last: 100, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
                        nodes {
                            name
                            createdAt
                            url
                            releaseAssets(last: 6) {
                                nodes {
                                    name
                                    downloadCount
                                    downloadUrl
                                }
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                         pageInfo {
                               endCursor
                               hasNextPage
                               hasPreviousPage
                               startCursor
                             }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I found there is nothing output. And I found that is because all tags of FFmpeg are listed in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tags not https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/releases.

How to solve this question?

How to solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

There are no downloadUrls, because the FFMpeg project has not provided any downloadable files. As the https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/releases page shows, "**There aren't any releases here**"

If what you are trying to get is the source code tarball URLs, these are automatic URLs you can construct. GitHub packs these files on demand, when requested.

The URL template for downloading tarballs is documented at [Source code archive URLs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/downloading-source-code-archives#source-code-archive-urls)